Payment Gateways/Online Payments UK
I've used Paypal in the past as a quick and simple way to add a Pay Now button to a website.
The code for the form on the Pay Now page looked like this
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="client_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
        <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%=Price %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%=Product %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<%=ProductID %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/payment-complete.asp">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com/take-payment.asp">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
        <input type="image" src="http://www.example.com/img/pay-now-button.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>

I was able to pass Price, Product and Product ID to Paypal, pre populating the payment page with my variables. The payment-complete.asp page (sample code below) would receive data from paypal about the transaction:
Dim authToken, txToken
Dim query
Dim objHttp
Dim sQuerystring
Dim sParts, iParts, aParts
Dim sResults, sKey, sValue
Dim i, result
Dim firstName, lastName, itemName, mcGross, mcCurrency

authToken ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
txToken = Request.Querystring("tx")
query = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx=" & txToken & "&at=" & authToken

set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "POST", "http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
objHttp.Send query

sQuerystring = objHttp.responseText

If Mid(sQuerystring,1,7) = "SUCCESS" Then
Transaction was successfully, perform database update
ELSE
Transaction failed, tell customer
END IF

I've now gone to create a new paypal account to create a similar set up for another website and Ive discovered its no longer done this way.
So my question, is there a simple/similar system to this where I can pass a few variables like price, product name etc, and it takes the payment, and returns, if successful to the website

Are you seeking a non-Paypal recommendation? If so, the question is off-topic. Are you seeking an alternative Paypal solution? If so, the Paypal documentation should be your starting point. Either way, the question as it stands is not appropriate here. If you have programming issues with your chosen solution then we might be able to help at that point.

The integration method in your question is deprecated, although it may still function it should not be used for new integrations.  Possible things to use instead:

Standard JS SDK + REST API backend integration
Use some off the shelf pre-integrated solution. Just about all ecommerce options integrate with PayPal so search the web or start with the official PayPal partner directory.
The new "Pay link or button" solution at http://www.paypal.com/buttons . This does not have much functionality for programmers, no way to pass variables.

